# Code coverage for EJB's Using Wildfly-Arquillian-Gradle-Jacoco

Tags: gradle, code-coverage, wildfly-8, jboss-arquillian, jacoco

I am trying to set-up code coverage for my project. I am using Wildfly 8.2 server, gradle as a build tool, and JUnit and Arquillian for testing. In gradle I have configured jacoco plugin to generate code coverage. I have a task called **jacocoTestReport** which allows me to generate an html report.

**Something about running the tests:**
I am working on a multi module project, each sub-project has a Deployments class in which we have two methods - one for creating a shrinkwrap archive of REST classes and other for non-REST classes. In arqullian.xml we are configuring this as  **REST_CONTAINER** and **NON_REST_CONTAINER** and giving path to WildFly installation directory. When we run **gradle build test** , It will run the whole tests by deploying the REST.ear and non-REST.ear and generate the coverage reports.

The issue is code coverage for  EJB's and other server managed classes are showing 0% (From primary ananlysis of coverage report). Also I analysed the jacoco.exec, there I found the classes which are showing 0% coverage are not listed in the file (Mostly bean classes).

Can someone provide me the correct configuration which works for the combination: Wildfly-Arquillian-Gradle-Jacoco

Note: I am ok to use tools other than jacoco, tried cobertura but same result.

Comment: Hey, is code coverage for EJB's really impossible or something like that? It seems like no one has ever tried.

Comment: I get code coverage just fine for my EJBs. But I don't use Arquillian, which I guess is the root of the problem, as it causes tested classes to get reloaded on a custom class loader. The code coverage tool doesn't see the reloaded class (which is the one actually getting exercised), so you get 0% coverage.

Comment: @Rogério could you give some keywords or links how to configure it for custom class loader?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (but I used jboss7 should not be a problem) source:https://developer.jboss.org/thread/241883

```
 apply plugin: 'jacoco'  
jacoco {     
    toolVersion = '0.7.4.201502262128'  
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/jacoco")  
}  

dependencies {  
testCompile 'YOUR_ARQUILLIAN_ADAPTER'  
 testCompile 'org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-container:1.1.5.Final'
  testCompile 'org.jboss.arquillian.extension:arquillian-jacoco:1.0.0.Alpha7' 
}

// Important: add the Jacoco libs on the test classpath (required for the Jacoco Arquillian extension to work). 
sourceSets {  
     test.runtimeClasspath += configurations.jacocoAnt 

}
```

Comment: What would be maven equivalent of this config?